# I want to show the last record (row) from my database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

but I dont know how and where to place the sql code in php, could someone please help me? I know its something like `SELECT * FROM form ORDER BY 'Klant_id' ASC LIMIT 1`

```
<html>
    <header>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"  />
    </header>
    <body>

     <?php 
             //makes an connection to the db

             mysql_connect("localhost", "root", '') or die(mysql_error());
             mysql_select_db('databaseimage') or die(mysql_error());

             $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM form ORDER BY 'Klant_id' ASC LIMIT 1")
             or die(mysql_error()); 

             echo "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
             while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data)) 
             { 
             echo "<tr>";    
             echo "<th>surname:</th> <td>".$info['Surname'] . "</td> "; 
             echo "<th>insertion:</th> <td>".$info['Insertion'] . "</td> ";
             echo "<th>initials:</th> <td>".$info['Initials'] . "</td> ";
             echo "<th>name:</th> <td>".$info['Name'] . "</td> "; 
             echo "<th>sex:</th> <td>".$info['Sex'] . "</td> ";
             echo "<th>adress:</th> <td>".$info['Adress'] . "</td> ";
             echo "<th>postcode:</th> <td>".$info['Postcode'] . "</td> ";
             echo "<th>location:</th> <td>".$info['Location'] . "</td> ";
             echo "<th>private phone:</th> <td>".$info['Private_phone'] . "</td> ";
             echo "<th>mobile phone:</th> <td>".$info['Mobile_phone'] . "</td> ";
             echo "<th>work phone:</th> <td>".$info['Work_phone'] . "</td> ";
             echo "<th>private email:</th> <td>".$info['Private_email'] . "</td> ";
             echo "<th>work email:</th> <td>".$info['Work_email'] . "</td> ";

             } 
             Print "</table>"; 
             ?> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: it is there, whats the issue that you are facing

Comment: Rather than ASC limit 1 (ascending order, i.e. the 1st record..) do you want DESC limit 1 (descending order, i.e. the last record) ?

Answer (score 2):

Don't wrap the column `Klant_ID` with single quotes. Single quote is very different from backtick.

```
SELECT * 
FROM form tablename 
ORDER BY Klant_id DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM form tablename 
ORDER BY `Klant_id` DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

**Differences:**

`Backticks` ( ` )  are to be used for table and column identifiers, but are only necessary when the identifier is a **[MySQL reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)**.

`Single quotes` ( ' ) should be used for string values like in the `VALUES()` list.

`Double quotes` are supported by MySQL for string values as well, but single quotes are more widely accepted by other RDBMS, so it is a good habit to use single quotes instead of double.

Answer (score 1):

when you have primary key with auto_increment, you should fetch it using `DESC` descending order. in order to fetch the last inserted record.

try this.

```
SELECT * FROM form ORDER BY `Klant_id` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Still doesnt show last record, Am i doing it right exceipt that DESC?

Comment: i see no wrong in your script, are you getting any errors? chances might be you have given wrong mysql `username/password/database` and change this `Print "</table>";` to `echo "</table>";`

Comment: `'Klant_id'` is a string constant (a value). It is **not** the name of a column. Therefor all rows are "sorted" by the same value

Comment: ahha, didn't see it was actually a single quote. corrected. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you have primary key with auto_increment set. You can do it in two ways

**First**

```
SELECT * FROM form WHERE Klant_id=(select MAX(Klant_id) FROM form)
```

**Second**

```
SELECT * FROM form ORDER BY Klant_id DESC LIMIT 1;
```